# Adding new item to List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, dart

i have this array of widget,
but i need to be able to add more item to it dynamically
How to add more item to this array of widget with a function?

```
  List<Widget> _tabScroll() => [
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1),
          color: Colors.grey[100]
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0),
        child: Text(_tab1),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1),
          color: Colors.grey[100]
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0),
        child: Text(_tab2),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1),
          color: Colors.grey[100]
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 5.0, 12.0, 5.0),
        child: Text(_tab3),
      ),
    ),
  ];
```

this is the controller for the tab

```
  TabBar _tabBarLabel() => TabBar(
    tabs: _tabScroll(),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your getter

```
List<Tab> get tabs => [
  Tab(...),
  Tab(...),
  Tab(...),
];
```

with instance variable

```
List<Tab> tabs = [
  Tab(...),
  Tab(...),
  Tab(...),
];
```

And use

```
tabs.add(Tab(...));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the list length doesn't change even when i add it by initstate

Comment: User CopsOnRoad is correct.  This is the right way to handle this.  I noticed in your original code that you're treating it like a function instead of a variable. If you use the method that CopsOnRoad suggests, and then return the result, you can keep the function and still manipulate the list. You might consider sharing your code in order to see what the problem is.

Comment: okay, i got this error after changing the list with the code above

`Error: A method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the method declaration.
  List<Tab> _tabs => [`

Comment: @Ray, can you update your post with the solution I provided so that I can test it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to be manipulating a list in your code, here are some other simple list operations that might be able to help you.  I created a dartpad file here so that you can play with them, and I marked two that will be helpful to you with your specific question:
https://dartpad.dev/a6f78b9ad58a589e7415d9b1625950b6

```
// Create firstList and add object to the end of firstList 
// THIS ONE will help you with your initial question
      List<String> firstList = ['Chicago', 'Santiago', 'São Paulo'];
      firstList.add('Tokyo'); 

// Adds to firstList at index number.(indexed from zero)
// THIS ONE will also help you with your initial question, but if you 
//    want to be more precise with where you insert your element
      firstList.insert(2, 'Mexico City'); 

// Create secondList and add entire secondList to end of firstList
// THIS ONE will help with your initial question if you decide to make 
// changes in bulk. (build secondList first with your changes, and add it to 
// your initial list all at once.
      List<String> secondList = ['Stockholm', 'Moscow', 'Paris']; 
      firstList.addAll(secondList); 

// Create thirdList and add to firstList at index "0" in firstList
// THIS ONE will help you with your initial question if you need to create
// a list ahead of time and insert it at a specific place all at once.
      List<String> thirdList = ['New York', 'San José', 'Buenos Aires']; 
      firstList.insertAll(0,thirdList); 

// Removes specific object in firstList
      firstList.remove("San José"); 

// Removes object at specific index in firstList
      firstList.removeAt(0); 

// Removes last object in firstList
      firstList.removeLast(); 

// Removes everything between 5 and 7 (where 7 is not inclusive) in firstList
      firstList.removeRange(5,7); 

// Find the index of a given object in firstList
      int bestCity = firstList.indexOf("Chicago"); 

// Finds index of first object that meets some criteria (in this case, starts with S);
      var firstS = firstList.indexWhere((city)=>city.startsWith("S")); 

// Same as the previous, but instead of starting at zero, it starts with the index of the included integer
      var secondS = firstList.indexWhere((city)=>city.startsWith("S"), firstS + 1);
```

Comment: All of those methods can be used for any object.  In fact, if you're doing any kind of operations with a list, you're forced to use them.  Perhaps you need a SetState() widget in a stateful widget to make it work? User CopsOnRoad is correct, using tabs.add(Tab(...)); is the way to go.  it your list length isn't changing, then I would suspect a mutable / immutable issue.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  If so, I'd greatly appreciate if you'd select the answer and give my answer an upvote. if not, please let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: I haven't check it yet, but thanks for the help. I will revisit this when I have time to check it back.